# Sonarqube with dotnet core works fine on command line but not from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, .net-core

I'm trying to launch Sonarqube on a .NET Core 2.0 solution from Jenkins using SOnarQube MsBuild on Windows.

It works fine when i execute the following script from Jenkins workspace:

```
C:\SonarQube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:XXXX.Campaigns /n:CI /v: /d:sonar.host.url=http://x.x.x.x:9000 /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.projectBaseDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI"
dotnet clean
dotnet build
C:\SonarQube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

But when i execute the same command from Jenkins, i got this message:

> The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was
>   unable to collect the required information about your projects.
>   Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in
>      between the begin and end steps.
> 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild
>      has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards
> 3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been
>      launched from the same folder

I use Jenkins 2.46.2 - MSBuild 15 - Sonarqube 6.7 & Sonar MsBuild 4.0.2.892. I tried using Jenkins build steps, command step, command step with a script without success. On a classical .Net 4.5.2 project, it works.

Comment: Hi @Greg, what version of SonarC# is installed on your SonarQube server? If it is older than 6.7 the .NET Core analysis will fail with the same error. Please, also note that accidentally the SonarC# and SonarQube have same versions for some time, but they are different products.

Comment: Hi! I installed Sonar C# 6.7.1 (build 4347).

Comment: A silly question, but - what's the language of your project? C# or VB.NET?Also, could it be that the compilation is failing for some reason?

Comment: C# .NET Core. The compilation succeed. And with my script, the end to end process succeed. It fails only when it's executed from Jenkins.

Comment: Are you building a solution, or just a project file (csproj) in Jenkins? The .NET Core projects don't have ProjectGuid property in the csproj by default and you need to either add one (it is an xml element) with a unique Guid to each project, or just add the projects to a sln. This way Visual Studio will assign Guids in the solution file, but you will have to build the solution, not the projects. If the scanner cannot find the ProjectGuid of a project it does not generate the ProjectInfo.xml and fails with the same error.

Comment: If my previous comment does not help, would it be possible to send me the logs from the Jenkins execution? It would be very helpful if you run the dotnet command with `-v` switch and also the scanner begin command with `/d:sonar.verbose=true`. You could write me directly to valeri dot hristov atsonarsourcecom, or create a new issue in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp and attach the logs there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins was running as local system user. I change it to a normal Windows user and it did the trick. dotnet build was not using Sonarqube dedicated targets.
Thanks you @Valeri!

Comment: FYI version 4.1 of the scanner will add an explicit message covering this case to make it easier to diagnose: see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-374