# SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins -The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

**Install Info is...**
sonarqube-6.7.1 | sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778 | sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892| msbuild 14 | Java SE Development Kit 8 | .NET Framework 4.6.2

And I made windows batch file to build and scan(sonar). but some projects are ok. but some projects are failed.
**batch file is...**

> step 1 . SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis
>
> step 2 . call "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CSS_SQ\trunk\Build\build.bat"

Our Build.bat is customized, I have tried only use Build.bat not include SonarQube, and it was working fine.

> step 3 . SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis

**error message is...**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CSS_SQ>exit 0 
[CSS_SQ] $ "C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" end /d:sonar.login=****** ********
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
Default properties file was found at C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.

> The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to
>   collect the required information about your projects. Possible causes:
>     1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
>     2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
>     3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder

Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
14:36:16.988  Creating a summary markdown file...
14:36:16.989  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
ERROR: Execution of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 1)
Finished: FAILURE

About the Possible causes, I have checked 1 and 2 ,it's correct,but I am not sure for 3. I am guessing the .sonarqube file should be in the same folder with .sln file, then when I set the batch files I need to set the path in Additional arguments column. But I can't find any clue to set that yet. What makes this error message? and How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third option means that the "begin" and "end" commands must be run from the same folder, e.g. the current folder should be the same when running the commands(if you execute `cd` before the scanner commands the printed paths should be the same).

**Edit:**
This particular problem seems to be caused because the build is executing older version of MSBuild. Please, make sure that you run MSBuild 14 or 15 in your analysis builds.

**Older suggestion (still generally valid)**

We just investigated [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631950/sonarqube-with-dotnet-core-works-fine-on-command-line-but-not-from-jenkins) which is caused by the user the Slave Agent service is authenticated with. To check if yours is the same, run the `begin` step of the scanner with `/d:sonar.verbose=true` and in the output you should see lines like these:

```
12:34:56.479  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to C:\...
12:34:56.482  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to C:\...
```

If the paths at the end are subfolders of `C:\Windows` then you need to change the Jenkins slave agent's Windows Service user with a domain user (and not Local System):

[image]

Comment: Do you mean changing the user for Jenkins?

Comment: You need to change the user that the Jenkins slave agent windows service is authenticated. By default it is local system, you need to change it to a domain user (this is the recommended way anyway).

Comment: I tried changed the jenkins user ,accroding to [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3958] steps, but it didn't work.

Comment: It changed from C:\Windows\system32\... to C:\Users\Administrator\...    
I got the same error @Valeri - SonarSource

Comment: Please, execute the `begin` step with `/d:sonar.verbose=true` and msbuild.exe with `/v:diag` and send me the output of begin, msbuild and end steps to valeri dot hristov atsonarsourcedotcom. It would be of great help too if you send me also the zipped `.sonarqube` folder that is created during the build in you solution's root dir.

Comment: I just sent the mail to you @Valeri - SonarSource, with .sonarqube.7z and output.txt. thanks