# Jenkins SonarQube for .NET Core Fails, but powershell script works

Tags: powershell, jenkins, asp.net-core, msbuild, sonarqube

I am trying to run a Jenkins pipeline for SonarQube analysis. I have written a powershell script that runs the analysis just fine; however it fails on the `end` step when run in the pipeline.

Here is the correct result from PowerShell:
https://pastebin.com/eCaDXgmi

Here is the failed result from Jenkins:
https://pastebin.com/mXgTiq5g

Here is the source of the PowerShell script:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SQScannerMSB\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe' begin /k:HC /n:HC /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 /d:sonar.login=REDACTED
& 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' msbuild /t:Rebuild
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SQScannerMSB\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe' end /d:sonar.login=REDACTED
```

Here is the relevant Jenkins Pipeline Code:

```
stage('SonarQube') {
    powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '.\\sonar.ps1')
}
```

Comment: Compare the environment variables, i.e. compare the output of `set`. There might be differences..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs it looks like it might be the same problem as in [Sonarqube with dotnet core works fine on command line but not from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631950/sonarqube-with-dotnet-core-works-fine-on-command-line-but-not-from-jenkins) i.e. running as a non-local account.

From v4.1, the Scanner for MSBuild will give a specific warning in this case - see [SonarMSBRU-374](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-374).

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution!