# SonarQube - C# Code not being displayed on Dashboard

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am having an issue with SonarQube 6.7 where it is not displaying any C# code issues or bugs, during the analysis I can see C# is being analysed and the build is successful but when I check the SonarQube Dashboard it is only showing Typescript and XML.

I am using Jenkins to build the project using Mono as all our building is done on Ubuntu 16.04.

Setup as follows:

**Jenkins 2.89.2 on Ubuntu 16.04**

**SonarQube Version 6.7 (build 33306) on Ubuntu 16.04 (Separate server)**

**Sonar C# 6.8.1**

**SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.1**

**Mono 5.10.0 Stable**

Using a Pipeline In Jenkins I am doing the following:

```
node {
    sh 'mono ~/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/MSBuild/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /key:12345678FAKEKEY9l02998745'
    sh 'dotnet restore WSP1.sln'
    sh 'dotnet msbuild WSP1.sln'
    sh 'mono ~/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/MSBuild/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end' } }
```

The above pipeline script works without any issues.

When I run this pipeline I can see that the C# code is being Analysed, this is just a snippet of code being analysed:

```
Services/Project1/Services/Project1EventsShould.cs(130,21): warning S1186: Add a nested comment explaining why this method is empty, throw a 'NotSupportedException' or complete the implementation. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CSharpAnalysis/WSP1/test/Unit/Unit.csproj]
Services/Project1/Services/Project1EventsShould.cs(137,21): warning S1186: Add a nested comment explaining why this method is empty, throw a 'NotSupportedException' or complete the implementation. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CSharpAnalysis/WSP1/test/Unit/Unit.csproj]
Services/Project1/Models/ZenEventShould.cs(24,17): warning S1481: Remove this unused 'date' local variable. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CSharpAnalysis/WSP1/test/Unit/Unit.csproj]
Services/Project1/Models/CollaborationUserShould.cs(16,17): warning S1481: Remove this unused 'sut' local variable. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CSharpAnalysis/WSP1/test/Unit/Unit.csproj]
```

At the end I get a SUCCESS, everything looks good but when I check SonarQube I can see that the uploaded code is being analysed for display in SonarQube, this usually takes a minute or so but when this is completed I can see that only TypeScript and XML is displayed.

In amongst the output I get some warnings, info and errors but nothing looks sinister, at the end of the output I get the success message

```
INFO: 68 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 281 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 1771ms, dir size=5 MB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 3908ms, zip size=2 MB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 5866ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonar.serverdomain.com:9000/dashboard/index/12345678FAKEKEY9l02998745
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://sonar.serverdomain.com:9000/api/ce/task?id=AKsdHc7FAKEIDVOeCzBYv
INFO: Task total time: 1:32.107 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:42.735s
INFO: Final Memory: 54M/397M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
14:59:57.577  Creating a summary markdown file...
14:59:57.59  Analysis results: http://sonar.serverdomain.com:9000/dashboard/index/12345678FAKEKEY9l02998745
14:59:57.591  Post-processing succeeded.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I have the full output handy, I just need to sanitize this to remove anything that may be sensitive, if you would like a look just let me know and I will post this.

I am pretty new to SonarQube so the issue I am having could be something silly but I have been ripping my hair out trying to figure this out.

**EDIT** : I was digging through the output again and noticed  2 warning in the following:

```
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ts: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
WARNING: WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
WARNING: WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
```

Comment: Could you run the build step with `/v:diag` and let me know whether you can see the following warning(s): `\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(261,5): warning : The project does not have a valid ProjectGuid. Analysis results for this project will not be uploaded to SonarQube. Project file:`?

Comment: When I first started out on this I was getting the ProjectGuid message but I have since resolved that. I ran this again with the v:diag and don't see the ProjectGuid message.

Anything else I could look out for ?

Comment: Could it be the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/a/48681079/4625433?

Comment: I tried all the steps above via shell and I get the same issue.;

I have updated the original post as I found 2 Warnings that look like they could be related.

Comment: @AmauryLevé have you anything else I could look out for ?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue on Sonarqube 6.7.4 (build 38452).

Solved by two steps:

1. After updating the built-in SonarC# plugin to version 7.2 (build 5463) (Uninstall-Restart-Install-Restart), and re-scanning, code issues (vulnerabilities, code smells, etc) showed up.
2. Introduced package [coverlet.msbuild](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) into test projects to generate coverage data, configured **Project - Administration - C# - OpenCover Unit Tests Reports Paths** to use `path/to/coverage.opencover.xml`. After re-scanning, test coverage data showed up.

Here are all the commands executed after above configurations:

```
    dotnet path/to/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"project-key"
    dotnet build
    dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
    dotnet path/to/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end
```